# How to make programmatic animations

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

I want to make programmatic animations in Silverlight without using storyboard and the zammle-svammle. In Flex/Flash the tweens and animations has a lot clearer API I think. How to make something similar in C#, or are there some third-party wrappers? Like TweenLite but for SilverLight? That would make me really happy!

But where to put the event?

[Source code of Programmatic Animation](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/sourcewindow.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[Working with Animations Programmatically in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189069%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#procedural_code)

Comment: Tell me where to put the method? Calling it in the constructor of the Mainpage clearly doesn't work. It should be bound to a some sort of completed event.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know where to put an event to start an animation when the view loads? If that is the case, then put it in the Loaded event on the view.

For example:

```
    public SomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SomeView_Loaded);
    }

    void SomeView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // start your animations here.
    }
```